# semi transparent modalViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiactionsheet

I've been researching this and it seems that the only way to do this is using UIActionSheet, the question is that my UIActionSheet only covers half of the screen, my code is:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[myViewController alloc] init];
UIActionSheet *myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                             destructiveButtonTitle:@"done"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
[myActionSheet addSubview:myVC.view];
[myActionSheet showInView:currentView];
[myActionSheet release];
```

Also how do I then dismiss this UIActionSheet from my MyViewController? Is there any better solution than this? Here's a screenshot of what I mean by loading half of the screen:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abDqV.png)

Here's [a sample project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19680269/ActionSheetIssue.zip) to illustrate my issue.

Comment: UIActionSheet behaves differently on iPhone and iPad, so I'm not sure why you tag with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIActionSheet` will increase or decrease it's height according to the number of `UIButton`s in it. What you can do is add another view above your view with your desired alpha. And remove it from subview and add in subview according to your requirement i.e. add subview when you are displaying actionsheet and remove when you are dismissing `UIActionSheet`. I hope this is relevant to your question and it will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the frame size of your TestViewController and method for adding the UIView as a subView of the `UIActionSheet`.

Make the following changes, and it is dismissing properly !

Implement `willPresentActionSheet` and `addSubView` in that method

```
- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender
{
UIActionSheet *myActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[myActionSheet showInView:self.view];
[myActionSheet release];   
}


- (void) willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet{

TestViewController *myVC = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
[actionSheet addSubview:myVC.view];

}
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` of the `TestViewController`, set

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0 , 320, 60);
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: why are you setting the height to be 60 instead of 480?

Comment: There is a problem with the frame size, with respect to the size of the `uiview` that you want inside the `UIActionSheet`. If you want to see the whole frame, you will have to use `modalViewControllers` for this task. You can remove cancel and done button. Check documentation its very easy to configure things :)